# Overlay steps in two columns

Tags: beamer, columns, overlays

I have the following slide:

```
\documentclass[beamer]{beamerswitch}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{My title}

  \begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Left side}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item First item;
        \item Second item;
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Right side}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item First item;
        \item Second item;
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I compile it, I get 9 pages.  On slides 1-2, only the title appears.  "Left side" appears on slide 3, and "Right side" appears on slide 7.

What should I change so that "Left side" appears on slide 1 already and there are no extra steps on slide 2 and 6?  I would like to keep the default overlay specification for the document.

**EDIT:** By trial and error, I found this solution:

```
\documentclass[beamer]{beamerswitch}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{My title}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{} %switch off for this slide

  \begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Left side}
        \begin{itemize}[<+(1)->]
        \item First item;
        \item Second item;
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{\uncover<4->{Right side}}
        \begin{itemize}[<+(2)->]
        \item First item;
        \item Second item;
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I don't understand why it does what it does.  If \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->} is in effect, beamer poses twice after printing the title.  Why?  It seems something is changing the value of the beamerpauses counter, but if I understand the manual correctly, neither the column nor the block environment is supposed to do that.  So what's injecting all these pauses?

Answer (score 2):

Next try. `[<+(1)->]`

```
\documentclass[beamer]{beamerswitch}
\usetheme{metropolis}
%\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{My title}

  \begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Left side}
        \begin{itemize}[<+(1)->]
        \item First item;
        \item Second item;
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{0.49\textwidth}
      \begin{block}{Right side}
        \begin{itemize}[<+(1)->]
        \item First item;
        \item Second item;
        \end{itemize}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have dozens of slides.  It would be a lot of extra work to add the overlays manually for each.  There must be a better way.

Comment: @GrB Fair enough. I changed the answer.

Comment: Again, I need to keep \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}.  Once you uncomment it, the problem is actually worse: only the title on slides 1-2, "Left slide" on slides 3-4, only "Right side" on slides 7-8.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can not say anything to why this happens, but the following fixes the issue for me through patching the `columns` and `column` environments with etoolbox:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% when using columns we get two empty pages before itemize without this, 
% when using \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->} 
\preto\columns{\addtocounter{beamerpauses}{-1}}
\preto\column{\addtocounter{beamerpauses}{-1}}
```

After that no empty pages appear before the list, and the overlaying runs through both columns like expected.